# Why is docker consuming so much VIRT memory?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I am running docker on my Mac OS X: 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

The point is that it seems to be consuming TOO much VIRT memory, if I am reading the `htop` output correctly.

[image]

Is this normal? Or is there any problem behind it? My laptop is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is illustrated by [moby/moby issue 31594](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31594).
That issue actually asks to run [`contrib/check-config.sh`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh) as a way to know more about the docker configuration being used.

The same issue is illustrated since 2015 in [#15020](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15020)

> It appears that Docker somehow does not respect `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` and will regardless allow the amount of virtual memory to grow to a number correlating to the number of CPUs being allocated to it.
>   (host is running macOS 10.13.2)

As commented:

> docker itself does nothing with that environment variable (or memory management of the processes inside the container); it sets up namespaces and cgroups for the process, which is all part of the kernel.

Comment: Does your answer mean that there is nothing I can do to fix this? I am not a sysadmin. So, your answer is not very clear to me.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos Yes, the gist of this answer is to highlight that the phenomenon is a known one, and does not have a current fix.